# Elegant way to prevent method from being called by different entities simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I have a method, `someMethod`, that is called when a) the user taps the view and b) when a user drags the view. In `someMethod`, there is a `UIView animateWithDuration` block that makes the toolbar on top of the view disappear, and resets its frame accordingly. If the user taps the view, than drags it, `someMethod` will be fired while the animation is still completing, and this isn't the behavior I want (simply canceling the animation doesn't work because the completion block still fires (even if I check the 'finished' BOOL). All things being considered, I just don't want this method to be fired while the animation is still in progress.

Obviously an easy solution to this is to set a manual lock with a `BOOL` and only allow the method to be called once the lock is free.

I'm wondering, is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? Possible to use GCD or some other library to accomplish this so it's more fool proof?

Update: I did try to use synchronized, the problem though is the method fires off the animation, finishes, but the animation is still running on another thread. Any other ideas?

Comment: A timer isn't automatically on another thread -- you'd have to have scheduled it there and have started the run loop for that thread. Is that actually the case?

Comment: @joshcaswell - I reworded my question, actually a timer isn't triggering the method, just another gesture is.

Answer (score 1):

A timer running out does not imply or require a secondary thread. You're in control of what thread a timer is scheduled on. If you just schedule the timer on the main thread, then both things happen on the main thread.

The suggestions of using `@synchronized` achieve the effect that a given block of code is not running for the same object (whatever is the parameter of `@synchronized`) at the same time, but that's not the same thing as saying it's not run on two different threads.

If you want to detect if a method is called on a thread other than the main thread and then shunt it over to the main thread, you can use `+[NSThread isMainThread]` and `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* re-call current method */ });`.

Comment: Actually it wasn't a timer sorry, it's too gesture recognizers, one a tap and the other a pan that can trigger the same block of code at the same time.

Comment: No, they can't. Both happen on the main thread and the main thread can't be doing two things at once.

Comment: I should have been more specific. There is an animation happening in this method. I have a little floating view with a toolbar (like a window) that I can drag around the screen. What happens is when the user taps this view, a method is called that makes the toolbar disappear in a short fading animation and the views frame resets itself (reduces its height and adjusts position) to account for the vanished toolbar. Also, when the user drags the view, this same method is also called to make the bars disappear if they happen to be present.

Comment: So if the user taps the view, then the bars start disappearing, and then they drag it, thus triggering the method again, it becomes messy because the frame is reseting itself twice. Do you think under this scenario it makes sense to use synchronize on this method?

Comment: How are you doing the animations? Edit your question to show the code. I still doubt that your method is being called on multiple threads. I suspect it's just being called multiple times on the main thread. You can log the value of `+[NSThread currentThread]`, `+[NSThread mainThread]`, and/or `+[NSThread isMainThread]` in your method to check.

Comment: I'm doing the animations with UIView animations (animateWithDuration). Sorry, I'm not trying to argue with you, more playing devils advocate and trying to understand. I guess what you're saying is if the method is being accessed from the main thread at the same time by both gesture recognizers and no threading is involved, then the processor must be just switching back and forth between the two processes? With that in mind is it most effective to just use the @synchronize like others are saying, or GCD better?

Comment: No, the method can not be "accessed from the main thread at the same time" (unless it's recursive). The main thread can't be doing two things at once. "the processor … switching back and forth between the two processes" would be threading, but I doubt it's doing that. I think it's calling your method (which runs to completion and returns) and then, at a slightly later time, calling it again in response to another "event". I suggest you use logging to figure out exactly what it happening before you try to solve what you *think* is the problem. Log method start and return as well as the thread.

Comment: How is it possible that my App can be listening for another tap / drag gesture while at the same time firing this animation? The animation would have to be on another thread, wouldn't it? Clearly it's still accepting gestures while the toolbar is animating and disappearing.

Comment: That's implementation detail that we're not privy to. It could be similar to a timer on the main thread. Each time it fires, it could advance the animation but between firings, events may delivered and handled. Or it could be animating on a background thread in a manner that's not available to us as non-Apple folks. I still suspect that any callbacks, like your method, will be invoked on the main thread. As I've said, you should test it.

Comment: I think we both agree, I just worded the title of my question incorrectly (and I updated it). I just meant the method is being called twice from somewhere. I did check and it is being called from the main thread. With this info, do you think synchronize is my best option? So I guess Apple must implement the gesturerecognizer to listen on a different thread?

Comment: `@synchronize` will have no effect (other than slowing things down a bit) given that your method is only ever called on the main thread. Its purpose is to prevent a given block of code from being entered simultaneously on two different threads. Given that your method is being called on the main thread, it's not being called simultaneously with itself.

Answer (score 1):

In modern iOS and OS X, the most elegant mechanism for controlling the execution is to use dispatch queues and blocks.  For a global lock, you can use a single serial queue and make request to it either synchronously or asynchronously, depending on whether you want the remainder of the execution on that thread to stop while you execute the critical code.

Declare your queue globally somewhere:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
```

So, when you launch, you'll create your queue:

```
myQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "CRITICAL_SECTION", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);    // FIFO
```

And when you want to execute the critical section of code, you use:

```
dispatch_sync( shpLockQueue, ^{
     // critical section here
});
```

Depending on your needs, you might want to call your method within one of these blocks, or you might want to have the block within the object that you are protecting.

You could use the main dispatch queue for this, if you needed to make sure that the routine is run on the main thread, but if that's unnecessary, it's going to be more efficient to use your own queue.   If you elect to use the main queue, you don't need to set up your own queue, or store it, you can just execute your code within:

```
dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     // critical section here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the @synchronized() block, Heres a great blog post on the explanation of it:

http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2006/10/synchronized-swimming.html

```
@synchronized(self) {
     [self someMethod];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well even using just a global variable, doesn't guarantee mutual exclusion, since the variable is copied to the register before being updated, if that indeed is what you meant by "manual lock BOOL ..." and unfortunately their aren't any really elegant solutions ....
Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html

Good luck.